# Placeholders not rendering after upgrade to django CMS 3.4

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am trying to upgrade django CMS to version 3.4.1 from 3.3.0. I am following the upgrade instructions [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/upgrade/3.4.html#upgrading-to-3-4).

After running

```
python manage.py migrate 
python manage.py cms fix-tree
```

I boot up my dev server and navigate to one of my pages, but none of the configured placeholders render.

I have verified that there are placeholders for the page, and plugins for those placeholders, in the database. Furthermore, by simply downgrading back to version 3.3.0, the placeholders and plugins all render correctly again.

I am not manually rendering the placeholders, as is mentioned as a possible issue [here in the upgrade notes](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/upgrade/3.4.html#manual-plugin-rendering). I am simply using the placeholder tag from `cms_tags` as mentioned in the documentation [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/templatetags.html#placeholder).

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? Let me know if I can provide any further information or clarification. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

It was asked that I provide an example template where the placeholder is not rendering. I have provided that below:

cms/home.html

```
{% extends 'cms/base.html' %}

{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{%block content %}
  <div class=" o-page-content o-page-content--home">
    <div class="o-hero o-hero--home">
      <div class="o-hero__content">
        <h1 class="o-hero__heading">
        <span class="o-hero__heading--topline">Your guide to</span>
        financial <span class="o-hero__heading--emphasized">health.</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="l-container">
      {{ block.super }}
      <div class="l-row">
        <div class="l-whole--xs c-under-hero">
          <h1 class="c-under-hero__text">Some content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="l-row">
        <div class="l-whole--xs">
          <div class="o-service-block">
            {% placeholder 'body' %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

cms/base.html

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags django_seo_js %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load imagekit %}
{% load pipeline %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8" {% if post.vertical %}ng-app="app" ng-controller="{{ post.vertical }}Controller"{% endif %}> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9" {% if post.vertical %}ng-app="app" ng-controller="{{ post.vertical }}Controller"{% endif %}>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en" ng-app="app"
  {% if request.current_page.verticalextension %}
    ng-controller="{{ request.current_page.verticalextension.vertical }}Controller as vm"
  {% endif %}><!--<![endif]-->

  <head>
    {% block appletitle %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- For the bots -->
    {% block metadata %}
      <!-- Meta -->
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
      <meta content="en-US" property="og:locale" itemprop="inLanguage"/>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block header_scripts %}
      {% seo_js_head %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% addtoblock "css" %}
      <!-- CSS Support -->
      {% stylesheet 'base' %}

      {% if request.toolbar.edit_mode %}
        {% stylesheet 'edit' %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endaddtoblock %}

    {% render_block "css" %}

    <!-- Style Sheet Files -->
    {% block css_files %}
      {% stylesheet request.onsite_stylesheet %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- Adding a favicon -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="{% static "img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" %}" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="{% static "img/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" %}" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static "img/favicon-32x32.png" %}" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static "img/favicon-16x16.png" %}" sizes="16x16" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="{% static "img/mstile-144x144.png" %}" />

    <!-- Include the dataLayer, Google Tag Manager, and the MF variable -->
    {% include 'cms/partials/data_layer.html' %}

    <!-- Analytics Tracking Codes -->
    {% include 'cms/partials/segment.html' %}

    <!-- Import jQuery before all other JS -->
    <script src='{% static "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" %}'></script>

    <!-- Taboola Script -->
    {% include 'cms/partials/taboola.html' %}

  </head>
  <body>
    {% cms_toolbar %}

    <!--=== Header ===-->
    {% block header_content %}
      {% include 'cms/partials/header.html' %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block breadcrumbs%}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block input_block %}
    {% endblock %}


    {% block footer_content %}
      {% include 'cms/partials/footer.html' %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block optin %}
      {% include 'cms/partials/optin.html' %}
    {% endblock optin %}

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        App.init();
      });
    </script>

    {% addtoblock "js" %}
      <!-- Mixpanel -->
      <script src='{% static "js/vendor/mixpanel.js" %}'></script>

      {% javascript 'base' %}
      <!-- Djangular Javascript -->
      <script src="{% static 'djangular/js/django-angular.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <!-- custom angular code -->
      {% javascript 'ng' %}

      {% javascript 'jq' %}
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&extension=.js"></script>

      {% if request.toolbar.edit_mode %}
        {% javascript 'edit' %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endaddtoblock %}

    {% block page_scripts %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% render_block "js" %}

  </body>
</html>
```

You can see the `{% placeholder 'body' %}` tag included in cms/home.html, and I have included cms/base.html since the home template inherits from it.

Comment: Hello, does this happen to all pages? or only a select few? And do these placeholders render on the toolbar? or nothing renders at all?

Comment: Hi @Paulo, thanks for your comment. This is happening on all pages, and no, the placeholders do not render on the toolbar. There is no option to navigate to the Structure view in the toolbar, so I think the placeholders themselves are not being recognized/rendered at all.

Comment: Can you post an example template that's not rendering placeholders? I had this recently, so maybe it'll help.

Comment: @markwalker_ , I edited the question to include snippets of an example template where a placeholder is not rendering. Hope this gives more context. Thanks in advance for the help!